# How can i restore a distorted image

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to restore a image that is distorted.
How can i restore a image

The example show how scanmarker app restore the image.
I want to develop like that example but i couldn't find any hints

[image]

Comment: You restore a distorted image by applying the inverse distortion. The difficult part is probably estimating the distortion and surely is specific for each image supplied. Maybe a different question asking for estimating the distortion for some specific images would help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ive been trying to find some inverse distortion algorithms but it seens not easy :(

Comment: It may become a bit easier if you would kind of specify your specific requirements. I guess there is no universal inverse distortion algorithm because it's not always clear what a distortion is. Applying an inverse distortion (as long as the distortions is reversible) should not be the big problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer below articles that will help you to kick start,

[Its an openCV Deconvolution Filter for blur correction](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/deconvolution.py)

[Its an pyimagesearch article on Image angle correction](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/)

[Image Alignment based on OpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/)